# Problemas con script de Perl que se conecta da base de datos Oracle

Tags: oracle, macos, perl

Estoy tratando de correr un script que se conecta a una base de datos Oracle, y obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> DBI connect('...,...) failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env 
> var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions
> ```

Estoy usando DBD::Oracle

Uso en MacOs Sierra

¿Qué es lo que puede estar fallando? Leí varios posts sobre esto y aparentemente hay varias causas pero nada de lo que leí me sirvió para solucionarlo.

¿Es posible que ORACLE_HOME esté mal? ¿y en ese caso qué valor tendría que tener?

Answer (score 1):

ORACLE_HOME debería valer igual a la ruta donde está instalado Oracle. Es decir, el lugar dentro del sistema de archivos donde están las librerías y binarios de Oracle.

En el caso de Windows, en vez de $ORACLE_HOME sería %PATH%